# CacheConfig is working in local system but when deployed on server its not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching

I am trying to hit an api and load the data in cache when application start.
The code is working locally and i can see cache is there but when deployed on server i see logs getting print for caching but it is not giving the data.

```
@Service
@CacheConfig(cacheNames = { "sampleData" })
public class TestService
{
    private static final String API = "LInk to some API the data of which need to be cached."

    private static final RestTemplate restTemplate = restTemplate();
    @Getter
    public static Map<String, String> testCountry = new TreeMap<>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);

    @Autowired
    TestService()
    {
    }

    @PostConstruct
    private static void getCountryData()
    {
        testCountry = TestService.code();
        log.info("Caching completed.");
    }

    public static Map<String, String> code()
    {
        log.info("Caching  is invoked {} ", API);
        Map<String, String> map = new TreeMap<>();

        try
        {
            ResponseEntity<SampleCountry[]> responseEntity = restTemplate
                    .getForEntity(API
                            , SampleCountry[].class);
            List<SampleCountry> SampleCountryList = Arrays.asList(responseEntity.getBody());
            map = SampleCountryList.stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(SampleCountry::getCode, SampleCountry::getName));

        }

        catch (HttpClientErrorException | HttpServerErrorException httpClientOrServerExc)
        {
            log.error("Error {} ",
                    httpClientOrServerExc.getStatusCode());
        }



        return map;
    }

    @Bean
    public static RestTemplate restTemplate()
    {
        RestTemplate restTemp = new RestTemplate();
        ((SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory) restTemp.getRequestFactory()).setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
        ((SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory) restTemp.getRequestFactory()).setReadTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);

        return restTemp;
    }
}
```

And i am invoking the same from another class.:

```
String countryName = Optional.ofNullable(TestService.testCountry).map(m -> m.get(code))
            .orElse(code);
```

The countryName is pulling the data from cache.

Comment: After a quick read, none of those Spring annotations sprinkled through your example code are doing anything for you.  In particular, that would mean that getCountryData() never gets called. (I did not think one _could_ mark a static method as @PostConstruct...).

Comment: getCountryData is PostContruct and is invoked when TestService.testCountry is called.